# How to filter GraphQL query with relational parameters, React Native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I have a React Native App that gives me a list of properties. Each property has it's own page and a link to a screen that lists all the notes that are associated with that property AND that user. So, a user can only see the notes that they have created for this specific property on this screen.

I'm having trouble writing a GraphQL query that gets all notes associated with the current property AND the current user.

My basic instinct is to write it like this...

```
const getNotes = gql`
  query getNotes {
    allPropertyNotes(filter: {
        AND: [{
            propertyId: ${this.props.navigation.state.params.id}
        }, {
            userId: ${this.props.screenProps.user.id}
        }]
    }, orderBy: createdAt_DESC) {
        id
        title
        body
    }
}
`;
```

But this doesn't seem to work because the query is defined outside of the component and doesn't have access to `this.props` (I'm assuming).

My next though was to do it like this

```
const getNotes = gql`
  query getNotes($userId: ID!, $propertyId: ID!) {
    allPropertyNotes(filter: {
        AND: [{
            propertyId: $propertyId
        }, {
            userId: $userId
        }]
    }, orderBy: createdAt_DESC) {
        id
        title
        body
    }
}
`;
```

But I'm not sure how to bind the variables to the ID's that I need them to be. Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: what kind navigation do you use ? Did you declare state management also for your navigation ?

Comment: how are you using this query? apollo? search docs for `variables`, not 'bind'

Comment: @xadm I'm using Apollo. I've used variables in a mutation that gets called on a form submit, but I just wasn't sure how to do it for a query and where to declare the variables? Would I call the `this.props.getNotes({})` in a `componentWillMount()` that just runs when the component will mount and throw the variables in there?

Comment: you can use mutation component or mutation passed as props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only 'query on mount' then just render `<Query/>` component using props as variables. [Example with variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#data)

The same you can do with [graphql() options.variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-variables)

Passing query (fired at start by default) and [many] mutations as props are for more complex cases. [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#compose)

Docs are not verbose here, you have to gather knowledge from many places/pieces or search for tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @xadm, ended up going with the `<Query />` component that way I was able to access the component's props inside the the query with the `variables` prop. I also had my query slightly off, it should have been `property {
  id: $propertyId
}` instead of `propertyId: $propertyId`